# Initial download (pre installation) happening at dial-up speed. Only 2+ hours to go!

Tags: downloads

I am new to ubuntu and attempting to download it to my desktop (wired) PC so I can create a CD so I can install it on my laptop PC (which is basically nonfunctional). Although I have a fast Internet connection, this download is moving at 72kbps or so. I've tried turning off the firewall, resetting the modem and router, rebooting the computer, and nothing works.

What else should I try, or is this really going to take nearly 3 hours?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Even though the best mirror is chosen for your geographical location when you click download at Ubuntu.com, you could try some alternative mirrors.

Answer (score 0):

It is not at dialup speeds. It is at least 8 times faster. Dial-up is in (kilo)bits per second, but the number you are getting is in (kilo)*bytes* per second. It will indeed take 3 hours but if your connection is DSL or low-end cable, it is using a good amount of your bandwidth efficiently.

Why is this?

You are getting bits(b) and bytes (B) confused. There are 8 bits in one byte. Therefore, a 1Mbps connection should ideally get 125Kbps, but the speed will be anywhere from 50-100 KBps. On dial-up, it would take over 24 hours.

```
700MB at ~70KBps
≈700000KB at 70KBps
≈10000Sec
≈3 hours
```